# How can I detect the selected option in Google Scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to extract which option has been selected from the code below in Apps Script. The idea is to create a function that assigns a value to a variable when you pick a different selection. This is easy with buttons, as you only need a target.matches to detect the click, but I don't know how to do it with the select menu.

```
<select class="form-select" id="selecccion">
 <option value="One">One</option>
 <option value="Two">Two</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById('seleccion").value